# Can I check that my SEED generated the address? Missing coins!

Tags: wallet, seed

I downloaded the IOTA wallet through the official site, then created a SEED, logged in and generated an address. I attached it to the tangle and then transferred some coins from Bitfinex.
I have checked on Bitfinex and it says complete, but the balance is still zero in my wallet (Version 2.5.7)
I have tried umpteen times to generate new addresses with no luck, and my original address doesn't show in my history.

Is there any way of finding out if my SEED generated the address that I have sent my coins to? Or any way of finding out if the address I used is attached to my SEED??

I am at my whits end with this, how on earth can it be so easy to lose coins, this is supposed to be 'nextgen' technology and it seems far to easy to make a mess or lose things!

This is the address I generated which shows COMPLETE, but god only knows where they are!! HAXTGIJOYYSLYHUOCXCRPIWRWZISFRZNRRWGRYLP9MPKTZCYHLMVQSMESJCCMVEALHLVMHWBYGANKBNRYXBNPCVWC9

Many thanks in advance,

Matt

Answer (score 1):

Since the address you used was the first address you attached to the tangle (at least I assume this), it will come back as first address when you are generating new addresses. So if you have entered your seed again, you have to generate at most one address (and attach it to the tangle) so that you should be back at your balance.

When the addresses you see in the wallet (after attaching them) do not include your address, your seed has most probably a typo in it (or first/last character missing).

When you enter your seed, the wallet shows a 3-character checksum which you can use to quickly notice that you entered a different seed (if you still know the checksum of the original seed).

Depending on how you entered your seed initially (copy&paste, or typed it in), there [is a tool with a few options](https://github.com/FVANtom/find-typo-in-iota-seed) available which you can install locally, give it your "almost" seed and the correct address, and it will scan for common typos and if any one of them generates your address as first address (or another one if you give it a different index).

Comment: I've actually got a terrible sinking feeling that the Seed I have saved isn't the one I generated to use for the transaction. I recall generating one that I pasted into my notepad, then used it to create a paper wallet. And then I created a second one that I used (Or thought I used) for my transaction. I have checked my paper Seed and its the same as the one I am using to login, which suggest I am an idiot and haven't saved the correct Seed. I presume my IOTA are now lost forever as I don't have any copy of that Seed and no way to recover it!